# Disable all HTTPS pages on my site

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I installed an SSL cert on my WordPress site a few weeks ago. Now, I want it gone. I deleted it from the root directory but, alas, I have noticed the pages still exist in HTTPS. This is a real problem for me since Google also is indexing the SSL pages.

Don't ask why I want it gone. That's not important.

How do I fully deactivate all https pages? Please don't suggest I install a HTTPS > HTTP plugin that forces HTTP on all pages. I want it organically gone.

Comment: Well...how did you set it up in the first place? Reverse that process. Adding an SSL certificate alone won't make your site HTTPS.

Comment: Assumption, Apache. Edit the config file - lots of material on-line on its contents and its meaning

Comment: Ok, I called up my hosting company and I didn't have permission to uninstall it. So, they uninstalled it. Now, that it's gone, can I still forward any https attempts to http?

Comment: The https links are still showing in Google's search results. When a user clicks on it, it will go to a non-existent page now. Can I still direct them to the HTTP version?

Comment: Just so you know, rnevius, you cannot. I see you deleted your answer where you said "Absolutely" but you cannot.

Comment: There has to be a connection between the browser and the server before it can redirect. And if the SSL cert is removed, a connection cannot be made. Therefore, the only solution is to reinstall the cert.

Comment: Why do you think I removed my comment (not answer)? I re-read your comment, and realized I was incorrect. Take a chill pill

Comment: I said it because I don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect all `https` requests to `http` with this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Place that above the standard WordPress rewrite block.

Also, be sure your site address and WordPress location in Dashboard>>Settings are `http` and not `https`, and if they are `https`, change them and save settings *before* you add the rewrite rule to .htaccess.